# ActiveAdmin - Index as grid - multiple field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a picture model with attributes 'img' and 'caption'

I rendered the images using index as grid

```
index as: :grid, columns: 2 do |pic|
  link_to image_tag(pic.image), admin_pic_path(pic)
end
```

This renders all the images without any problem. I also want caption along with the images so that i have a heading for each image. 
Anyone knows how to solve this ?Is it possible to render multiple fields using index as grid ?

Answer (score 4):

I think if you want to write easy and clear code you should use [Arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre) instead of using Rails tag helpers like `link_to` and `image_tag`:

```rb
index as: :grid do |product|
    a href: admin_pic_path(pic) do
        img src: image_path(pic.image), alt: pic.title
        div pic.caption
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do the same without using Arbre

Comment: In this case you should concatenate strings with tags and call `html_safe` at the end. What the problem with Arbre? This is part of ActiveAdmin.